# Add jQuery to WordPress page

Tags: plugins, php, jquery

I need to add jQuery library to WordPress page. The page is rendered by a plugin shortcode.

I've used the below methods but I don't see it working for my jQuery script.

I tried to add these below script in main plugin file where the plugin name and version go.

DESN'T WORK:

```
function my_init() {
    if (!is_admin()) {
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    }
}
add_action('init', 'my_init');
```

DESN'T WORK

```
function my_init() {
    if (!is_admin()) {
        // comment out the next two lines to load the local copy of jQuery
        wp_deregister_script('jquery'); 
        wp_register_script('jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js', false, '1.4.2'); 
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    }
}
add_action('init', 'my_init');
```

I actually need to add below library to my WordPress front end page?

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js
```

but if i use it directly like below then it works.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Second, How can see it loaded in my browser loaded along with other code?

Comment: You can see if your browser has loaded the script in the network panel of your development tools.

Does your theme include a call to `wp_head()`

Comment: It is highly recommended to use the jQuery version that comes with WordPress core.

Comment: Hook your action onto `wp_enqueue_scripts`, not `init`.  Your first example should work fine then, assuming, as @veganista pointed out, that your theme calls `wp_head()`

Answer (score 0):

I think wordpress only loads jQuery when you specify it is a dependency for another script that is loading on that page:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', '/path/script.js', array('jQuery');
```

If there is no other script then try loading it like a normal script with full path to the file:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'myJquery', '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js');
```