# Difficulty loading jQuery with wp_enqueue_script

Tags: theme-development, jquery, wp-enqueue-script

forgive me but I am an amateur so I have limited knowledge.

I want to know the best way to add jQuery to my custom WordPress theme. Previously I just used the following code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

I have learnt that apparently this is not the best practice way and that the best practice way is to use the wp_enqueue_script function to add jQuery. Therefore I created an index.php and functions.js file which I have copied down below.

**html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            jQuery('.enqTest').css('color','blue');
        });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p class="enqTest">This font should be blue</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

**functions.js**

```
<?php
function adding_jquery{
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','adding_jquery');
```

My aim here is to use jQuery to change the font color of the text however I am trying to use wp_enqueue_script to load jQuery. It does not work. What am I missing here?

I have looked at other questions, [interestingly another user said jQuery can only be loaded when it has been marked as a dependancy for a different script](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/185826/add-jquery-to-wordpress-page). Is this true? Would I then need to take the jQuery function out of my index.php file, add it to a new script file and register then enqueue that script file in the adding_jquery function in my functions.php file?

Comment: Did you put the second code in functions.js, or .php file? (There is functions.js above the code - is it a typo?)

Comment: I can't believe that was it. Thanks, if you submit an answer I will mark it as "accepted".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wp_enqueue_scripts` is a PHP hook, so you should use it in PHP. It won't work, if you add it to some JS file.

So if it's not a typo and you really put this code to `functions.js` file, then that's the reason it doesn't work.